# Windows Phone ARM instruction manual

Tags: nokia-lumia-730

I have a Nokia Lumia 730 Dual Sim but it's operating system has been corrupted. Although it can be restored to it's original state but instead I want to use it for some other purpose/experiments like testing assembly programs etc. But for that I need it's ARM instruction manual. Where can I get it?

If anybody has some other ideas which can be tested on such phone please tell me.